# Is it OK to use covariance of types with abstract factory pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm learning about design patterns from GOF book.

There is one thing about Abstract Factory pattern implementation that makes me mingle. I'll start with code:

Abstract Factory:

```
public interface AnimalsFactory {

    Animal getWaterAnimal();

    Animal getLandAnimal();

    Animal getFlyingAnimal();
}
```

Concrete Factory:

```
public class SafariAnimalsFactory implements AnimalsFactory {

    @Override
    public Hippo getWaterAnimal() {
        return new Hippo();
    }

    @Override
    public Giraffe getLandAnimal() {
        return new Giraffe();
    }

    @Override
    public Vulture getFlyingAnimal() {
        return new Vulture();
    }
}
```

I used covariance of types so factory methods return concrete products instead of abstract products (Animal).

I like it but doesn't this violate rule of thumb about products being encapsulated from the client? Or maybe I'm overthinking this.

Comment: `Lion getFlyingAnimal()` - cuz lions can fly

Comment: @SvetlinZarev somehow I missed that xD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using covariance in this situation is great. This is a perfect case for demonstrating the power of covariant overrides in Java, because it lets you have the best of both worlds:

- If you deal with a factory by programming to its interface, the implementation is perfectly hidden from you
- If, on the other hand, you deal with the factory directly, you can avoid casts.